# Did I solve a basic derivation problem correctly?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

The following problem is from *Mathematical Logic* by Ian Chiswell and Wilfrid Hodges, 2007.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by the OP, $\{\psi,\phi\} \vdash (\phi\to(\psi\to\phi))$, could be the sequent the authors expect as a solution to Exercise 2.4.3 (b).

There is no question about the conclusion of the sequent. It is the bottom line of the derivation. The question concerns what statements are in the set of undischarged assumptions.

That set could contain some of the following statements: $\phi$, $\psi$, or even $(\psi\to\phi)$. That it does not contain $(\psi\to\phi)$ can be seen by the use of the Sequent Rule $(\to I)$ in the derivation. That statement is derived. Since no statements are discharged in the derivation, the set of statements that are undischarged are $\{\psi,\phi\}$.

Hence the desired solution to the exercise could be the sequent $\{\psi,\phi\} \vdash (\phi\to(\psi\to\phi))$.

---

Chiswell, I., & Hodges, W. (2007). Mathematical logic. OUP Oxford.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly...

I think that, due to the fact that the assumption $\varphi$ has not been "crossed away", it is correct to consider it *undischarged*.

But $\psi$ is not listed explicitly as an assumption; thus, I think that the correct answer is :

> $\{ \varphi \} \vdash (\varphi \to (\psi \to \varphi))$.

The following :

> $$\dfrac{ \varphi }{ \psi \to \varphi }$$

is a correct application of the rule ($\to$-I); "semantically", if $\varphi$ is *true*, then $\psi \to \varphi$ is *true*, for $\psi$ whatever.

Comment: I'm trying to solve it with what the book presented prior to the problem. The book didn't say that an unmentioned assumption can be put into the left side of if-then statement. @MauroALLEGRANZA